# How do I include a JAR file on command line?

Tags: groovy

For reasons particular to my case, I am running groovy programs as follows:

```
java -jar groovy-3.0.7-indy.jar Test.groovy
```

It runs fine.

I now want to include classes located in another jar.  I am trying:

```
java -jar groovy-3.0.7-indy.jar -cp More.jar Test.groovy
```

But it can't seem to find any classes in More.jar.  How can I run this so that Test.groovy can import and use classes inside More.jar?

Thank you!

Blake McBride

Comment: Don't use -jar option. From documentation: When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.

Comment: @daggett -cp is a documented argument to groovy-3.0.7-indy.jar not java.

Comment: this parameter only for `groovy -cp xyz.jar script.groovy` command line

Comment: check this comment in groovy code:    https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/4b0c510e1b2903ae8582411793f1c1bed5341172/src/main/java/groovy/ui/GroovyMain.java#L173

Comment: use command line `java -cp J1.jar;J2.jar groovy.ui.GroovyMain Test.groovy`